# Safety Interlock

Tags: automation

I'm looking to design a basic system that I believe requires a solenoid interlock.

The basis of the system is a swinging gate. The gate has two positions, as you might expect - open and closed. There is a process that will be run which will only run when the gate is closed and locked. A microprocessor ties together the whole control system.

So, when the process is initiated (via a button), I want the system to check whether the gate is closed. If the gate is closed, I want it to be automatically locked. Otherwise I do not want the process to run. Once the process is finished, I want the gate to be unlocked.

A part solution to this problem is the use of a limit switch or hall effect sensor, however, this doesn't help with the locking part. As far as I'm aware there are products on the market which provide both functions in one.

My first thought of a device to use is some sort of locking solenoid switch. As far as I'm aware, these can be used to detect proximity (i.e. if the gate is closed) and then used as a lock. I'm not entirely what to search for. Some products I have found seem to only be compatible with some sort of proprietary safety controllers.

In terms of compatibility, I guess what I'm looking for is a device that acts like a switch. In my head, I'm imagining that when the gate is in the closed position a contact that is NO becomes closed. Furthermore, my thoughts for the lock is that it is a solenoid controlled by a contactor or similar.

What suggestions do you have for setting up a system like this? Is there is particular type of component I should be looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, your problem statement is far too vague to make this an answerable question.  Computational devices are absurdly literal, so you must specify exactly what you want to happen, under what conditions. It looks like there are a few words missing to even have a grammatically complete statement, but even putting those back in with an edit is probably still going to be short of an answerable question.

Comment: I've tidied up the question, adding further information and additional thoughts.

Comment: Still not really an answerable question.  Actuators and sensors are conceptually distinct; sometimes sensors are built into actuators, but you might as well think of them as distinct functional items.

Comment: Your safety interlock has to check if locking the gate was successful. How do you do that? You need another switch for that. That's what those lock&switch combinations are for, I guess.

Comment: There are systems where the operator has to hold two switches ti prove their hands are not in the machine... accidents still occur because they put a brick on one switch - the boundless stupidity...

Comment: If this is an actual safety system, and to be used in any commercial/industrial setting, I cannot advise strongly enough against 'rolling your own'.  Determine your require SIL level, and use an appropriate, commercial device, such as a trapped-key switch, or RFID tagged mag-lock. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_integrity_level

Comment: I wouldn't dream of a DIY safety system in any Commerical setting. It's a bit of fun for myself. I thought that there might be locks similar to magnetic door locks which can also detect the presence of the door.

Comment: If the gate is closed by a motor, how about putting an encoder on the motor shaft?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/download-pdf/XCSTE5311 Please note that machine safety has to use a safety relay, safety plc or some approved safety MCU.

Usually a standard PLC or MCU is used with additonally a safety relay. The safety relay disconnects power to the mahine and it has safety inputs, outputs.

What you are asking is a safety interlock switch/lock. You wire the safety contact as any other emergency switch, once opened the machine has to stop. When you close the doors, it'll lock them unless you supply the solenoid to unlock the door. Usually we put a push button to activate the solenoid that stays enegized for few minutes or less, this due to solenoid overheating and burning if they are constantly turned on.